# Check if Second Level Address Translation (SLAT) is installed

Tags: windows, hyper-v, windows-command-prompt, microsoft

There are different instructions online to show that you have **Second Level Address Translation (SLAT)** enabled as a dependency to install WSL 2 and Docker.  The simplest way is to run "systeminfo.exe" in various Windows OS versions.  How can I run this command without the command prompt from closing?  When I run this, a bunch of text appears really quick and exits.

```
Do Intel® Processors Support Second Level Address Translation (SLAT)?
- Press the Windows* key and type command prompt.
- Type systeminfo.exe.
- Check the Hyper-V Requirements section.
```

Also, does the "CoreInfo" program that Microsoft developed below give the exact same answer?  I like to avoid installations for something as simple as this, so I'd rather not install CoreInfo.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/coreinfo

Comment: Just find the processor model number in task manager and look it up via Google? The Intel data sheets usually mention it? Most CPUs from the last 7 years have it though. Heck if you had included the CPU model in your question you would probably have an answer already.

Comment: Open the command prompt window, and then run `systeminfo` in there.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just query WMI from powershell? All built in to the system

```
Get-WmiObject –Class Win32_Processor | Select-Object –property __Server, SecondLEvelAddressTranslationExtensions
```

Comment: I got "{COMPUTER NAME} .... False" before and after I installed Hyper-V in Windows.  I finally got WSL 2 and Docker to run after after installing Hyper-V.  So that was the issue.  I must have SLAT according to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Need to restart my machine, but keeping my notes here for later.

[image]

Here is the CoreInfo output when I run a command prompt as "Run As Administrator":

```
C:\Users\mac\Downloads\Coreinfo>Coreinfo.exe

Coreinfo v3.52 - Dump information on system CPU and memory topology
Copyright (C) 2008-2021 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9820X CPU @ 3.30GHz
Intel64 Family 6 Model 85 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel
Microcode signature: 0200005E
HTT             *       Hyperthreading enabled
Error loading driver:
This driver has been blocked from loading
Querying CET support requires admin rights
HYPERVISOR      *       Hypervisor is present
VMX             -       Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
SVM             -       Supports AMD hardware-assisted virtualization
X64             *       Supports 64-bit mode

SMX             -       Supports Intel trusted execution
SKINIT          -       Supports AMD SKINIT
SGX             -       Supports Intel SGX

NX              *       Supports no-execute page protection
SMEP            *       Supports Supervisor Mode Execution Prevention
SMAP            *       Supports Supervisor Mode Access Prevention
PAGE1GB         *       Supports 1 GB large pages
PAE             *       Supports > 32-bit physical addresses
PAT             *       Supports Page Attribute Table
PSE             *       Supports 4 MB pages
PSE36           *       Supports > 32-bit address 4 MB pages
PGE             *       Supports global bit in page tables
SS              *       Supports bus snooping for cache operations
VME             *       Supports Virtual-8086 mode
RDWRFSGSBASE    *       Supports direct GS/FS base access

FPU             *       Implements i387 floating point instructions
MMX             *       Supports MMX instruction set
MMXEXT          -       Implements AMD MMX extensions
3DNOW           -       Supports 3DNow! instructions
3DNOWEXT        -       Supports 3DNow! extension instructions
SSE             *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions
SSE2            *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 2
SSE3            *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 3
SSSE3           *       Supports Supplemental SIMD Extensions 3
SSE4a           -       Supports Streaming SIMDR Extensions 4a
SSE4.1          *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.1
SSE4.2          *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.2

AES             *       Supports AES extensions
AVX             *       Supports AVX instruction extensions
AVX2            *       Supports AVX2 instruction extensions
AVX-512-F       *       Supports AVX-512 Foundation instructions
AVX-512-DQ      *       Supports AVX-512 double and quadword instructions
AVX-512-IFAMA   -       Supports AVX-512 integer Fused multiply-add instructions
AVX-512-PF      -       Supports AVX-512 prefetch instructions
AVX-512-ER      -       Supports AVX-512 exponential and reciprocal instructions
AVX-512-CD      *       Supports AVX-512 conflict detection instructions
AVX-512-BW      *       Supports AVX-512 byte and word instructions
AVX-512-VL      *       Supports AVX-512 vector length instructions
FMA             *       Supports FMA extensions using YMM state
MSR             *       Implements RDMSR/WRMSR instructions
MTRR            *       Supports Memory Type Range Registers
XSAVE           *       Supports XSAVE/XRSTOR instructions
OSXSAVE         *       Supports XSETBV/XGETBV instructions
RDRAND          *       Supports RDRAND instruction
RDSEED          *       Supports RDSEED instruction

CMOV            *       Supports CMOVcc instruction
CLFSH           *       Supports CLFLUSH instruction
CX8             *       Supports compare and exchange 8-byte instructions
CX16            *       Supports CMPXCHG16B instruction
BMI1            *       Supports bit manipulation extensions 1
BMI2            *       Supports bit manipulation extensions 2
ADX             *       Supports ADCX/ADOX instructions
DCA             -       Supports prefetch from memory-mapped device
F16C            *       Supports half-precision instruction
FXSR            *       Supports FXSAVE/FXSTOR instructions
FFXSR           -       Supports optimized FXSAVE/FSRSTOR instruction
MONITOR         -       Supports MONITOR and MWAIT instructions
MOVBE           *       Supports MOVBE instruction
ERMSB           *       Supports Enhanced REP MOVSB/STOSB
PCLMULDQ        *       Supports PCLMULDQ instruction
POPCNT          *       Supports POPCNT instruction
LZCNT           *       Supports LZCNT instruction
SEP             *       Supports fast system call instructions
LAHF-SAHF       *       Supports LAHF/SAHF instructions in 64-bit mode
HLE             *       Supports Hardware Lock Elision instructions
RTM             *       Supports Restricted Transactional Memory instructions

DE              *       Supports I/O breakpoints including CR4.DE
DTES64          *       Can write history of 64-bit branch addresses
DS              *       Implements memory-resident debug buffer
DS-CPL          -       Supports Debug Store feature with CPL
PCID            *       Supports PCIDs and settable CR4.PCIDE
INVPCID         *       Supports INVPCID instruction
PDCM            *       Supports Performance Capabilities MSR
RDTSCP          *       Supports RDTSCP instruction
TSC             *       Supports RDTSC instruction
TSC-DEADLINE    -       Local APIC supports one-shot deadline timer
TSC-INVARIANT   *       TSC runs at constant rate
xTPR            *       Supports disabling task priority messages

EIST            *       Supports Enhanced Intel Speedstep
ACPI            *       Implements MSR for power management
TM              *       Implements thermal monitor circuitry
TM2             *       Implements Thermal Monitor 2 control
APIC            *       Implements software-accessible local APIC
x2APIC          -       Supports x2APIC

CNXT-ID         -       L1 data cache mode adaptive or BIOS

MCE             *       Supports Machine Check, INT18 and CR4.MCE
MCA             *       Implements Machine Check Architecture
PBE             *       Supports use of FERR#/PBE# pin

PSN             -       Implements 96-bit processor serial number

PREFETCHW       *       Supports PREFETCHW instruction

Maximum implemented CPUID leaves: 00000016 (Basic), 80000008 (Extended).
Maximum implemented address width: 48 bits (virtual), 46 bits (physical).

Processor signature: 00050654

Logical to Physical Processor Map:
**------------------  Physical Processor 0 (Hyperthreaded)
--**----------------  Physical Processor 1 (Hyperthreaded)
----**--------------  Physical Processor 2 (Hyperthreaded)
------**------------  Physical Processor 3 (Hyperthreaded)
--------**----------  Physical Processor 4 (Hyperthreaded)
----------**--------  Physical Processor 5 (Hyperthreaded)
------------**------  Physical Processor 6 (Hyperthreaded)
--------------**----  Physical Processor 7 (Hyperthreaded)
----------------**--  Physical Processor 8 (Hyperthreaded)
------------------**  Physical Processor 9 (Hyperthreaded)

Logical Processor to Socket Map:
********************  Socket 0

Logical Processor to NUMA Node Map:
********************  NUMA Node 0

No NUMA nodes.

Logical Processor to Cache Map:
**------------------  Data Cache          0, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
**------------------  Instruction Cache   0, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
**------------------  Unified Cache       0, Level 2,    1 MB, Assoc  16, LineSize  64
********************  Unified Cache       1, Level 3,   16 MB, Assoc  11, LineSize  64
--**----------------  Data Cache          1, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
--**----------------  Instruction Cache   1, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
--**----------------  Unified Cache       2, Level 2,    1 MB, Assoc  16, LineSize  64
----**--------------  Data Cache          2, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
----**--------------  Instruction Cache   2, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
----**--------------  Unified Cache       3, Level 2,    1 MB, Assoc  16, LineSize  64
------**------------  Data Cache          3, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
------**------------  Instruction Cache   3, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
------**------------  Unified Cache       4, Level 2,    1 MB, Assoc  16, LineSize  64
--------**----------  Data Cache          4, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
--------**----------  Instruction Cache   4, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
--------**----------  Unified Cache       5, Level 2,    1 MB, Assoc  16, LineSize  64
----------**--------  Data Cache          5, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
----------**--------  Instruction Cache   5, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
----------**--------  Unified Cache       6, Level 2,    1 MB, Assoc  16, LineSize  64
------------**------  Data Cache          6, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
------------**------  Instruction Cache   6, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
------------**------  Unified Cache       7, Level 2,    1 MB, Assoc  16, LineSize  64
--------------**----  Data Cache          7, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
--------------**----  Instruction Cache   7, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
--------------**----  Unified Cache       8, Level 2,    1 MB, Assoc  16, LineSize  64
----------------**--  Data Cache          8, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
----------------**--  Instruction Cache   8, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
----------------**--  Unified Cache       9, Level 2,    1 MB, Assoc  16, LineSize  64
------------------**  Data Cache          9, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
------------------**  Instruction Cache   9, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
------------------**  Unified Cache      10, Level 2,    1 MB, Assoc  16, LineSize  64

Logical Processor to Group Map:
********************  Group 0

C:\Users\mac\Downloads\Coreinfo>
```

Here is the installation of Hyper-V:

[image]

Comment: You appear to be running these inside a virtual machine. You need to check the host.

Comment: No, this isn't a VM.  It's a desktop computer.